# Syntax error while using TwitterAPI for OAuth

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

I am trying to read tweets using TwitterAPI module provided in python but I am not able to successfully execute through OAuth process.

```
>>> from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

>>> api = TwitterAPI(sgKlULRabMMK8LWL1xlyQZ5Tp, 
9CJQLJeJy1zab4Vb6z8bBo7danOYpgXmZRLAM0sQ8TWjgzeomr, 2478453955-
DoOmd6G10VYvKNEKupbcNAxxdYrWCainf8URjDF, 
00nxI4KDE7DekFcUDuUr60ziTuk03V9YQafuIYz7dYOUP1)
File "<stdin>", line 1
api = TwitterAPI(sgKlULRabMMK8LWL1xlyQZ5Tp, 9CJQLJeJy1zab4Vb6z8bBo7danOYpgXmZRLAM0sQ8TWjgzeomr, 2478453955-DoOmd6G10VYvKNEKupbcNAxxdYrWCainf8URjDF, 00nxI4KDE7DekFcUDuUr60ziTuk03V9YQafuIYz7dYOUP1)
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

This gives me syntax error , Basically what i followed was

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key,access_token_secret)
```

I read at few places that few other people faced the same issue and were asked to generate new consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret which i did , but i still face the same issue .

I hope you guys might rescue me from this as i am new to this .

Solution:-

```
 1> Quotes was missing as said in answer below 

 2> The invalid syntax was also due to long line python issue.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the back-tick **`** character (by accident, I assume) before typing `from`.

No crying in baseball; no backticks in Python

**EDIT**

And this is wrong too:

```
api = TwitterAPI(sgKlULRabMMK8LWL1xlyQZ5Tp, 9CJQLJeJy1zab4Vb6z8bBo7danOYpgXmZRLAM0sQ8TWjgzeomr, 2478453955-DoOmd6G10VYvKNEKupbcNAxxdYrWCainf8URjDF, 00nxI4KDE7DekFcUDuUr60ziTuk03V9YQafuIYz7dYOUP1)
```

You have to put quotation marks around the keys, like this:

```
api = TwitterAPI("sgKlULRabMMK8LWL1xlyQZ5Tp",
 "9CJQLJeJy1zab4Vb6z8bBo7danOYpgXmZRLAM0sQ8TWjgzeomr",
 "2478453955-DoOmd6G10VYvKNEKupbcNAxxdYrWCainf8URjDF",
 "00nxI4KDE7DekFcUDuUr60ziTuk03V9YQafuIYz7dYOUP1")
```

Comment: Not really actually that backtick was done to Highlight or gray the code here as I am new to it . On my terminal there is no backtick

Comment: That does not help either.

Comment: Works for me.  Check for a typo.